# I wanted to get one messages from each session to process as Fan out

Tags: azure-servicebus-queues, azure-durable-functions

I have session enabled service bus queue where I am pushing 9 messages (3 messages for 3 sessions, for example).

Now I am trying to use azure durable function where I am using service bus queue trigger as client function and I want to orchestrate 1 messages processing from each session, means 3 activities function runs in parallel.

I have below client function code, but I here I observed that every time only 1 messages coming from single session,

```
[FunctionName("FanOutIn_Run")]
    public static async Task Run(
        [ServiceBusTrigger("file-scanner-queue", Connection = "ServiceBusConnectionString",
            IsSessionsEnabled = true, AutoCompleteMessages = false)] ServiceBusReceivedMessage[] messages,
        ServiceBusMessageActions messageActions, [DurableClient] IDurableOrchestrationClient starter, ILogger log)
    {

        var serviceBusReceivedMessages = messages.ToList();
        
        // only 1 message from 1 session coming here 
    }
```

I have also set maxConcurrentSessions = 10

```
"extensions": {
"serviceBus": {
  "sessionHandlerOptions": {
    "autoComplete": false,
    "maxConcurrentSessions": 10
  }
}
```

Can I alter this behavior? I want 1 messages from each session?

Comment: Your function is receiving a batch of messages rather than a single message. Are you trying to process different sessions in a fan-out manner or the messages from the same session? If the latter, that's not how sessions work.

Comment: @SeanFeldman, different session in a fan-out manner. I tried to debug it out, the count of `messages.ToList()` always 1

Comment: Different sessions get handled in parallel, up to a max number of parallel sessions defined. I'm not sure why you don't use that.